# What happends after you shed the last of your casual karma?At this stage do you merge with God?

Tags: gods, brahman, moksha

After shedding the last residual of your casual karma. You merge with god, does this mean you literally become God or do you still retain individuality ?
If you do retain individuality, what does it mean then that we're his manifestations ?

Comment: You already merge god, the moment you become Jivanmukta.